# Не подгружается метка на яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, php, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>На карте</title>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1?apikey=2891e1a9-da5c-4ccb-96f0-0cc3f9381faa&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init() {
      ymaps.geocode('г. Обнинск пр. Ленина 104, офис 1', {
        results: 1
      }).then(function(res) {
        var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
        var myMap;
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
          center: [55.105357, 36.596853],
          zoom: 15,
          behaviors: ['default', 'scrollZoom']
        });
        myMap.controls.add("mapTools").add("zoomControl").add("typeSelector");
        ymaps.geocode(myMap.getCenter(), {
          boundedBy: myMap.getBounds(),
          results: 1
        }).then(function(res) {
          $("#toggle").attr('value', 'Скрыть карту');
          myMap.options.set('scrollZoomSpeed', 1);
        });
        ymaps.geocode('г. Обнинск пр. Ленина 104, офис 1').then(function(res) {
          myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.105357, 36.596853], {
            balloonContentHeader: '<b>СВЕЖИЙ ВЕТЕР, туристическое агентство</b>',
            balloonContentBody: 'г. Обнинск, пр. Ленина 104, офис 1 <br><em>8(484)394-22-44</em>',
            balloonContentFooter: 'Как добратся: &nbsp; <a href=http://maps.yandex.ru/?rt=~36.596853,55.105357&sll=36.596853,55.105357&sspn=0%2C0&rtm=atm&source=route&rtt=mt&rtn=0&ll=36.596853,55.105357&spn=0%2C0&z=55.105357,36.59685315&l=map" target="_blank">Транспортом</a>  &nbsp;/ &nbsp; <a href="http://maps.yandex.ru/?rt=~36.596853,55.105357&sll=36.596853,55.105357&sspn=0%2C0&rtm=atm&source=route&ll=36.596853,55.105357&spn=0%2C0&z=15&l=map" target="_blank">На машине</a>'
          }, {
            hideIconOnBalloonOpen: true,
            balloonShadow: false
          });
          myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        });
      }, function(err) {})

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div align=center><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="map" style="width:580px;height:380px"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас здесь ошибка `myMap.controls.add("mapTools").add("zoomControl").add("typeSelector")`. Можно найти с помощью дебаггера.